# Can 'profiting off' be replaced with 'profiting off of'?

Tags: questions

> “It can easily become exploitative by **profiting off** the communities that are being targeted right now,” she told Reuters.

[Link to source](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/amp/hijab-gets-more-acceptance-from-business/3960021.html)

Can 'profiting off' be replaced with 'profiting off of'?

Comment: Please consider trying to format your questions better.  You can see some examples of how people have reformatted your questions [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/143343/revisions) and [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/143216/revisions).

Answer (score 1):

Just "profitting off" - without the *of* - is fine.

"Off of" expressions are common in colloquial AmE, although sometimes considered less correct.

A recent [report](https://www.vanityfair.com/news/2017/10/elizabeth-warren-eviscerates-equifax-for-profiting-off-screw-up) in *Vanity Fair* is headlined:

> Elizabeth Warren Eviscerates Equifax for Profiting “Off of Its Own Screw-Up”

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off%20of) defines "off of" as "off", and says:

> The *of* is often criticized as superfluous, a comment that is irrelevant because *off of* is an idiom. It is much more common in speech than in edited writing and is more common in American English than in British.

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/off_of) considers "off of" to be "non-standard".  It gives examples including:

> ‘I pinched this next bit off of a website somewhere’
>   ‘bullets were bouncing off of the shield’
>
> ‘She smiled brightly as she got off of her bicycle and skipped over and on to the porch.’
>
> ‘Being able to bounce my ideas off of other like-minded people was even more of a relief.’
>
> ‘Do not tear labels off of medication or cleaners.’

Oxford states that "off of" is "widely accepted in American English. Nevertheless, it is regarded as incorrect in standard modern British English."